# TurtleBot Bringup Not Connecting to Port

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using the TurtleBot3 Waffle with Intel Joule processor for about a month now, and everything has been working very smoothly up until yesterday. Yesterday I followed the same process I usually use to set the TurtleBot up to communicate with a Remote PC:

[Remote PC]

1. Run `roscore`
2. Run `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch`

[TurtleBot]

1. Power up the robot
2. Run `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch`

After I run these steps, I usually am able to publish/subscribe to the various ROS topics the robot publishes/subscribes to. Yesterday I ran this setup and received this console output after launching the turtlebot3_robot.launch on the TurtleBot:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://[hostname]:45747/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13
 * /turtlebot3_core/baud: 115200
 * /turtlebot3_core/port: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /turtlebot3_lds/frame_id: base_scan
 * /turtlebot3_lds/port: /dev/ttyUSB0

NODES
  /
    turtlebot3_core (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    turtlebot3_diagnostics (turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics)
    turtlebot3_lds (hls_lfcd_lds_driver/hlds_laser_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://[master_uri]:11311

process[turtlebot3_core-1]: started with pid [2603]
process[turtlebot3_lds-2]: started with pid [2604]
process[turtlebot3_diagnostics-3]: started with pid [2605]
[INFO] [1522418950.044044, 0.000000]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1522418950.263477, 0.000000]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud
```

And that's as far as it gets. It's getting hung up on connecting the OpenCR port. The only similar scenario to mine that I've seen asked about on here is at the following link: [https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/69](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/69). I've followed all the instructions in the answers provided with no successful outcome.

Strangely enough, I let the robot charge overnight, and when I powered it on again this morning, it worked fine for the first 3 or 4 times I ran the boot sequence above. Then I tried to start again after 3-4 successes, and I ran into the same issue. It gets stuck on the connecting step.

I am able to connect to the OpenCR board and flash the turtlebot3_core firmware from the Arduino program, so I know I have connectivity to the board. It's just the turtlebot3_robot.launch sequence that seems to be having trouble with connecting. I'm planning to re-flash the BIOS for the Intel Joule processor being used alongside the OpenCR board. I have tried powering on and off, unplugging and plugging back in every port possible to try and diagnose the issue, but I haven't had any success.

If more information is needed, I would be happy to provide it. Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287099/turtlebot-bringup-not-connecting-to-port/) by [nprof50](https://answers.ros.org/users/34403/nprof50/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerald](https://answers.ros.org/users/35237/gerald/) on 2019-03-29**:
Hello,
I have the same problem, do you find a solution?
Thanks.

**Comment by [nprof50](https://answers.ros.org/users/34403/nprof50/) on 2019-03-29**:
Turns out it was a power issue. The battery was too low to power the OpenCR board, so make sure your battery is charged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to reiterate the solution:

Turns out it was a power issue. The battery was too low to power the OpenCR board, so make sure your battery is charged.

---

Originally posted by [nprof50](https://answers.ros.org/users/34403/nprof50/) with karma: 26 on 2019-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0